How can one teaches business from Quran or hadith to be self sustained
Islam is answer to everything in life, yet our education fail to teaches us that. I was wondering if there are any verse or books in Islam teaching trade or business. I am 9-5 employee and lose my sleep over work, failed jobs etc. Now I know my heart cannot take manager's annoyance or performance reviews etc as I also suffer from anixety. My dad passed away when I was little so I am learning Quran with my kids now, and had no sound education.
In islam are there ways to teach us how to do business e.g. I worry too much for loosing job that I lost my sleep over it etc. I know Allah is the sustainer but I also believe I need to work hard in order for Allah to sustain me but I have no skill which I can  proudly say "I am good at x".

The wolve-men smell your anxiety, and demand more, and more, and more. Face them, and don't forget to have another place where you can work. Not based on Islam, but on hard understanding of real life business and human nature. And, improve your English.
